# ViewPager is empty after returning from back stak even with using of childFragmentManager and FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android-viewpager, fragmentmanager

I have a view pager, it works fine when I open fragment with it at first time. After returning this fragment from back stack I have an empty screen. I'm using ChildFragmentManager for FragmentStatePagerAdapter but it still doesn't work. Found temporary solution by setting new adapter every time in onResume but seems to me this solution is not best way to solve this issue. Kindly ask you to help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
public class RecentReviewsCollapsedContainerFragment extends AbstractFragmentView
    implements RecentReviewsCollapsedContract.View {

@BindView(R.id.recent_reviews_view_pager)
ViewPager mRecentReviewsViewPager;

@BindView(R.id.server_connection_button_try_again)
Button mTryAgainButton;

RecentReviewsViewPagerAdapter mViewPagerAdapter;
RecentReviewsCollapsedContract.Presenter mPresenter;
List<Review> mReviews;

public RecentReviewsCollapsedContainerFragment() {}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recent_reviews_collapsed_container, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    mPresenter = new RecentReviewsCollapsedPresenter(this);
    mPresenter.loadReviews();

    setUpViewPager();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if ( mViewPagerAdapter != null ) {
        cleanChildFragments(getChildFragmentManager());
        mViewPagerAdapter = new RecentReviewsViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), mReviews);
        mRecentReviewsViewPager.setAdapter(mViewPagerAdapter);
    }
}

@Override
public void startProgress() {
    showProgress();
}

@Override
public void stopProgress() {
    hideProgress();
}

@Override
public void showConnectionErrorMessage() {
    showServerConnectionError();
}

@Override
public void showNoItems() {
    showNoItems();
}

@Override
public void setReviewsList(List<Review> reviews) {
    if ( mViewPagerAdapter == null ) {
        mViewPagerAdapter = new RecentReviewsViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), reviews);
        mRecentReviewsViewPager.setAdapter(mViewPagerAdapter);
        mReviews = reviews;
        return;
    }
    mReviews = reviews;
    mViewPagerAdapter.setData(reviews);
}

private void setUpViewPager() {

    mRecentReviewsViewPager.setPageMargin(getResources()
                    .getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.viewpager_margin));
}

private void cleanChildFragments(FragmentManager childFragmentManager) {
    List<Fragment> childFragments = childFragmentManager.getFragments();
    if (childFragments != null && !childFragments.isEmpty()) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = childFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        for (Fragment fragment : childFragments) {
            ft.remove(fragment);
        }
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

}

```
public class RecentReviewsViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
private List<Review> mReviews;

public RecentReviewsViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

public RecentReviewsViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Review> reviews) {
    super(fm);

    mReviews = reviews;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    RecentReviewCollapsedItemFragment reviewItem = new RecentReviewsViewPagerAdapter.RecentReviewCollapsedItemFragment();
    reviewItem.setReview(mReviews.get(position));

    return reviewItem;
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mReviews.size();
}

public void setData(List<Review> reviews) {
    mReviews = reviews;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public static class RecentReviewCollapsedItemFragment extends Fragment {
    private Review mReview;

    @BindView(R.id.recent_reviews_item_scroll_view)
    ObservableScrollView scrollView;

    @BindView(R.id.recent_reviews_collapsed_item_text_view_date)
    TextView mDateTextView;

    @BindView(R.id.recent_reviews_collapsed_item_rating_bar_dealer)
    RatingBar mDealerRating;

    @BindView(R.id.recent_reviews_collapsed_item_rating_bar_user)
    RatingBar mEmployeeRatingBar;

    @BindView(R.id.recent_reviews_collapsed_item_text_view_title)
    TextView mTitle;

    @BindView(R.id.recent_reviews_collapsed_item_text_view_review_author_name)
    TextView mAuthorNameTextView;

    @BindView(R.id.recent_reviews_collpsed_item_image_view_verified)
    ImageView mVerifiedCustomerImageView;

    @BindView(R.id.recent_reviews_collapsed_item_text_view_verified_customer)
    TextView mVerifiedCustomerTextView;

    @BindView(R.id.recent_reviews_collapsed_item_text_view_review_content)
    TextView mReviewContentTextView;

    @BindView(R.id.recent_review_collapsed_item_ratingbar_customer_service)
    RatingBar mCustomerServiceRatingBar;

    @BindView(R.id.recent_review_collapsed_item_ratingbar_quality_of_work)
    RatingBar mQualityOfWorkRatingBar;

    @BindView(R.id.recent_review_collapsed_item_ratingbar_friendliness)
    RatingBar mFriendlinessRatingBar;

    @BindView(R.id.recent_review_collapsed_item_ratingbar_pricing)
    RatingBar mPricingRatingBar;

    @BindView(R.id.recent_review_collapsed_item_text_view_recommend_dealer_value)
    TextView mRecommendDealerValueTextView;


    public RecentReviewCollapsedItemFragment() {}


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recent_review_collapsed_item, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        bindData();

        setOnClickListener(scrollView);
        setOnClickListener(mDateTextView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    public void setReview(Review review) {
        mReview = review;
    }

    private void bindData() {
        mDateTextView.setText(mReview.getDate());
        mDealerRating.setRating((int) mReview.getRating());
        mEmployeeRatingBar.setRating((int) mReview.getEmployeeRating());
        mTitle.setText(String.format("\"%s\"", mReview.getTitle()));
        mAuthorNameTextView.setText(String.format("- %s", mReview.getReviewUserName()));
        setVerifiedCustomer();
        mReviewContentTextView.setText(mReview.getReviewBody());
        mCustomerServiceRatingBar.setRating(mReview.getCustomerServiceRating());
        mQualityOfWorkRatingBar.setRating(mReview.getQualityRating());
        mFriendlinessRatingBar.setRating(mReview.getFriendlinessRating());
        mPricingRatingBar.setRating(mReview.getPricingRating());
        setRecommendDealer();
    }

    private void setVerifiedCustomer() {
        if ( mReview.isVerifiedCustomer() ) {
            mVerifiedCustomerTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mVerifiedCustomerImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return;
        }
        mVerifiedCustomerTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mVerifiedCustomerImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    private void setRecommendDealer() {
        if ( mReview.isRecommendDealer() ) {
            mRecommendDealerValueTextView.setText(getActivity().getString(R.string.yes));
            return;
        }
        mRecommendDealerValueTextView.setText(getActivity().getString(R.string.no));
    }

    private void setOnClickListener(View view) {
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FullReviewFragment fragment = new FullReviewFragment();
                fragment.setReview(mReview);
                ((ViewContainer) getActivity()).showFragment(fragment, true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems you don't reattach adapter on restart

```
if ( mViewPagerAdapter == null ) {
    mViewPagerAdapter = new RecentReviewsViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), reviews);
    mRecentReviewsViewPager.setAdapter(mViewPagerAdapter); // <<<<
    mReviews = reviews;
    return;
}
mReviews = reviews;
mViewPagerAdapter.setData(reviews);
```

this line must be called whenever mRecentReviewsViewPager has no adapter